# Square of numerical first-order derivative

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-difference-methods

I wish to obtain the square of the numerical derivative of a variable $\phi(x)$, i.e. $\left(\frac{d\phi}{dx} \right)^2$. For this, I am using the central difference technique as shown below.

$$ \left(\frac{\phi(x+h)-\phi(x-h)}{2h}\right)^2.$$

However, I am unsure whether the method that I am using is correct. I am unable to find any resource regarding this. Hence, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think that your approach is wrong? It seems perfectly fine to me.

Comment: I see. However, the same could be achieved by multiplying the forward difference of $d\phi/dx$ with the backward difference of $d\phi/dx$. If so, then the confusion is: which of the two is correct?

Comment: The choice of any approximation depends very much on what your final goal is. Good approximations are not only accurate, but reflect key properties of the target. Your first approximation is second order accurate and *always* nonnegative, just like the target value. Your new approximation is first order accurate, but can assume negative values. The order might not matter as much, but I can imagine computer programs where an unexpected sign change can cause a crash.

Comment: Aha. Was not at all thinking about the change in sign owing to the use of the second method. I guess, in a sense, that makes the original method more correct than the other one. Thank you sir.